# Microsoft Advertising SDK- Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ads

I need to get the Advertising SDK for XAML I(Windows 8.1) for VS 2015. I can't find any link online for XAML for VS 2015. I only got the Silverlight SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download "Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone" and add the reference in "Windows Phone 8.1 -> Extensions" section.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fba0c64e-358e-4b86-8e69-d6b57771d92a

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you need?
[link](http://adsinapps.microsoft.com/en-US/sdk)

Wasn't that difficult to find using advertising sdk xaml..

Comment: Already seen that page. It's for Visual Studio 2013 and older. Not for VS 2015.

Comment: Hmm strange because the website says "within visual studio 2013 update 2 and later"